# SQL - Potential 100K records out of 2M . Best method to design database

Tags: sql-server, performance

My basic table contain 2 million records of users with 30 columns.

Once in a while there is a new activity open for participation of potentially 100K users (different groups for each activity).
Each user will do a self authentication , and his/her activity data will be saved for further use.

**What is the best method to design the database?**

1. Copy 100K into Users_In_Activity table with all required and needed details from the base table. a new PK (Users_In_Activity Primary Key) will be create for each record.

   - In this method, there will be no joint between the tables and the search 
     for a record will be done by one PK (Users_In_Activity) from only 100K of records.
2. Copy 100K of the user basic details for authentication to Potential_Users_In_Activity table. a new PK will be created (include the user PK) and a new User_In_activity PK will be created.

   - For each successful authentication, a full record will be created in Actual_Users_In_Activity table.
   - Search for a record will be done by one PK (Users_In_Activity) from only 100K of records.
   - in this method the is join between 2 tabled with one PK (Users_In_Activity)
3. For each successful authentication, a full record will be created in Actual_Users_In_Activity table.

   - in this method the there is no join, but the search will be from all the 2 million records.

.

.

**Summarise:**

Method 1 : Create 100K of 30 columns records. Search from 100K of records , no need to create new records during activity. No join is needed. Only one table to work with.

Method 2 : Create 100K of 5 columns. Search from 100K of records. Create new records (30 columns) during activity (active users only). Join is needed. 2 table to work with

Method 3 : Search from 2M of records . Create new records (30 columns)  during activity (active users only). 2 table to work with

Comment: What kind of traffic do you expect? R/W ratio.

Comment: Why do you need to copy those 30 columns? Duplicating data is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Not really. Duplicating data for efficient queries is a good idea in nowadays standards.

Comment: I expect 30% participation (30K out of 100K), and per each user, for most of the users - one read and one write. Take in mind that there is going to be hundreds of activities during time (the 100K table is going to be eventually a huge one for history purposes).

Answer (score 2):

you didn't discuss the basic design,

User Table=2 million record,USERID is PK.This table only contain user details.

Activity Table=Activity Detail,ACtivityID is PK (no relation with user table here) .This table contain Activity detail whenever new activity is created.

User_Activity_Mapping=ActivityID,USERID (Copy 100K users here):This is user-activity relationship table here.

With proper indexing it will work ok.

let me know

Comment: user-activity relationship table is going to be huge one during time. Won't it be logical to search the user within the 2M and than preform an insert (or update) according to the actual number of participants in the activity?

Comment: @YanivBenYohana , OK  my doubts,when activity is first assign to 100k user before hand then they r know as potential users but when they are actually authenticated then they become Actual USER.Is potential user temporary ?Once activity is over then what happen to those records.Will you maintain History of potential user ? Explain any other thing which I have miss.

Comment: The activity include sending messages to those all 100K and that history need to be saved (few columns).  Other then that, if a user, is actual participating (response to invitation) then more than 20 different data need to be recorded .

Comment: So say out of 100K ,90K actually participated so they will be save in diff table with 20 column. Right ?Now when activity is over then what happen to those 90K record.will they be there or it is of no use. ?Just imagine after 5 activity how record you will have then it will be same thing.